Why is an audit hook not called in Python 3.12 but is called in Jupyter Notebook?
From my understanding the following function audit should be called when the Test object is created. This isn't the case, but why?
import sys

def audit(event, args):
    output = f'{event} with args={args}'
    print(output)

sys.addaudithook(audit)

class Test: 
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = Test()

If you copy the code in a Jupyter Notebook you get the following result:
compile with args=<ast. Module object at 0x7f466a6aeb90>,None)
exec with args=<code object ‹module> at 0x7f466a63bd70, file "/tmp/ipykernel_27420/3704920664-py", line 1>,)
compile with args=<ast.Module object at 0x7f466a6aec10>, None) 
exec with args=<code object ‹module> at 0x7f466a63bado, file "/ tmp/ipykernel_27420/3704920664-py", line 1>, )
sys._getframe with args=(<frame at 0x7f466a678d40, file '/home/user/.conda/envs/iiv/lib/python3.12/logging/init_.py', line 1616, code findCa
object._getattr_ with args=‹frame at 0x7f466aa812a0, file '/home/user/.conda/envs/iiv/lib/python3.12/logging/.init_.py', line 1672, code
object _getattr_with args=<frame at 0x7f466a66410, file '/home/user/.conda/envs/iiv/lib/python3.12/logging/init_.py', line 1527, code d
object._getattr_with args=<frame at 0x7f466a80d60,file '/home/user/.conda/envs/iiv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py'
object._ getattr_ with args=<frame at 0x7f466a80d60, file '/home/user/.conda/envs/iiv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py',


Yes. Regarding https://docs.python.org/3/library/audit_events.html it should be called. If you pack this code in Jupyter Notebooks, it works. But why?

I want to run an unsecured script in a unit test where I don't want to inspect the constructor. But please let's stick to the question itself and not my motivation. Why isn't the 'print(output)' executed in python3.12?

Yes, you are right and this is the problem. If you use Jupyter Notebook (also confirmed in the answer below), you get an output.

I don't know, this is simply the copy of my terminal. Please, let us discuss the question. Can you also reproduce the problem?

Have you ever tested it with a python script and jupyter notebooks? If not, than you cannot see the problem.

python3.8-12 tkinter 8.6
The messages you see when running the code in Jupiter Notebook are not about creating any Test objects but about a kernel activity. The code itself raises no audit events, so you can't see anything when running it as a script. For comparison, run the following script with Python:
# test.py

import sys, os
sys.addaudithook(print)
x = eval('{}')
x = id(x)
*_, files = next(os.walk('.'))
if files:
    with open(files[0]): pass

You'll likely see something like this, which means the audit hooks are working fine:
bash$ python3.12 test.py 

compile (b'{}', '<string>')
exec (<code object <module> at 0x7f0e9d0b39e0, file "<string>", line 1>,)
builtins.id (139700741970752,)
os.walk ('.', True, None, False)
os.scandir ('.',)
open ('test.py', 'r', 524288)

To intercept the object creation process using auditing, you need to inject sys.audit in the appropriate place. For example:
from functools import wraps, partial
import sys


def targeted_audit(event, event_args, target=None):
    if event == target:
        print(f'AUDIT: {event=}, {event_args=}', file=sys.stderr)

        
def inject_audition(func):
    event = repr(func)
    
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        sys.audit(event, args, kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    
    wrapper.event = event
    return wrapper


# define the class
class Test: 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        
# inject sys.audit
Test.__init__ = inject_audition(Test.__init__)
sys.addaudithook(partial(targeted_audit, target=Test.__init__.event))

# run the main script
x = Test(100500, value='something')

Alternatively, we can hardcode sys.audit directly into the package of interest, or we can track some specific events that occur when a tracked object is created. For example, when creating a tkinter.Tk() object, you're likely to notice a "builtins.id" event that is raised when the registering method requests the id of a wrapper around the main window destroyer. So you can try to use that to catch the moment of creating Tk():
import sys, _ctypes 
from functools import partial


class TkInitException(Exception): pass


def tk_init_audit(event, args, raise_exception:bool):
    '''Track id of a wrapper around Tk.destroy.  Set raise_exception=True
    to raise TkInitException when a Tk destroyer ID is caught.'''

    if event == 'builtins.id':
        obj_id = args[0]
        try:
            obj = _ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(obj_id)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'DEBUG: An error occurred when trying to recognise id: {e!r}', file=sys.stderr)
            return
        try:
            obj = obj.__self__
            if (obj.__class__.__name__ == 'CallWrapper'
                and obj.func.__name__ == 'destroy'
                and obj.func.__self__.__class__.__name__ == 'Tk'
            ):
                if raise_exception:
                    raise TkInitException()
                else:
                    print('WARNING: Tk() was created and loaded', file=sys.stderr)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        except TkInitException:
            raise
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'DEBUG: An error occurred when trying to match Tk.destroy: {e!r}', file=sys.stderr)
            

sys.addaudithook(partial(tk_init_audit, raise_exception=False))

# Run the main script
import tkinter as tk
junk = id(__name__)     # should be ignored
root = tk.Tk(useTk=0)   # should be ignored
root.loadtk()           # should catch the id of Tk.destroy
root.mainloop()

